# Sending request if property does not exist while destructuring JS object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, axios, fetch

I have object with property which should be destructred. But if it has false value I want to fetch it from backend.

```
const { property = await someMethodThatSendsRequest() } = myObject;
```

But this is not working. The question is - Is this even possible ?

Comment: So, is this "has a false value" or "does not exist"? In the latter case, your code should work as it is.

Comment: It receives null from backend and it does not work

Comment: of course it does work. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: @georg this is not working. do you have any messenger ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a variable as a default value:

```
const defaultProperty = myObject.property || await someMethodSendsRequest();
const { property = defaultProperty } = myObject;
```

Comment: that was my collegue's code:)  i was not sure if that should  work. so thought i am the stupid one for now knowing this hack

Comment: you don't need the last line actually

Comment: i understood your answer:) would it be better if i use ?? instead of ||

Comment: ?? is a new syntax, you may need transpile to make it works in some legacy browsers.

Answer (score 1):

In a matter of fact, yes. It is possible. However, your `property` needs to get accessed in order to get a result of `someMethodThatSendsRequest()` since default parameters are evaluated at [call time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#evaluated_at_call_time). A simple [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-cerf-qcubt?file=/src/App.js) that proves it.